# jquery range picker... sort of

Tags: jquery, slider

I am looking to create a slider similar to the [Yast Timetracker Slider](http://www.yast.com/timetracker/) in jQuery.

Is there a pre-built solution out there?
Or do I need to build my own?

Comment: Hi, Can you share i need the same thing to be achieved..

Answer (score -2, accepted):

See if you have any use of this http://jqueryui.com/demos/slider/#range

Comment: I think to do that I would need to do some heavy modifications... Would be easier to create my own one than to try to modify the ui one...

Comment: It shouldn't be such a big deal - jQuery slider supports start, stop, slide and change events and you could use those to trigger a jQuery dialog like in your example. There's also the create event which you could probably use to create a new slider once you reach the end values (previous, next buttons in that example).

Comment: oh no, the slider in the demo does a lot more, for example, try overlapping two (or more) times.

Comment: My bad, this does indeed seem like a very powerful piece of JavaScript.